# Implementing debugDescription for DebugPrintable in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, lldb

I'm trying to write my own debug description for a Swift class. My code looks like the following:

```
class SceneData : DebugPrintable {
    var fileName : String
    var scene : Scene
    var uuid : String

    var debugDescription: String = {
        return String(format: "<SceneData: {\n  fileName: %s\n  scene: %@\n}>", fileName, scene)
    }
    /*
     * More methods, etc.
     */
}
```

I'm getting the error `'SceneData.Type' does not have a member named 'fileName'`, but `SceneData` very clearly does have a variable `fileName` declared above. I'm also having similar issues when trying to use `self` within the string, and believe that this is related.

How can I make references to instance variables/`self` in the `debugDescription` string properly? I am pretty sure it is possible, both because [other people have said it is](http://ericasadun.com/2015/05/22/swift-logging/), and because it seems ridiculous to have an object's debug description not have any actual specifics about itself. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove `=`, because it should be a computed property.

```
var debugDescription: String{
        return String(format: "<SceneData: {\n  fileName: %s\n  scene: %@\n}>", fileName, scene)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I missed that. Or rather, didn't look up the syntax for a computed variable more closely.